# como trabajar con un item de un spinner

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

Yo tengo un spinner y cuando este en "Anual" quiero se modifique un EditText ,como podría hacer eso, este es mi código

```
val tipo_plan = listOf("Anual","Mensual","Individual")
val adapterTipo_plan = ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, tipo_plan)

val planTipo = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.PlanTP)
planTipo.setAdapter(adapterTipo_plan)
```

Comment: Adrian, puedes elaborar mejor tu situacion? No queda muy clara.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para esto tendras que agregar el evento `onItemSelectedListener` que se ejecuta cuando un elemento del `Spinner` es seleccionado y luego verificar que se selecciono el indice 0 que corresponde a An`introducir el código aquí`ual en el array:

```
planTipo.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) { }

    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
        if(position == 0)
        {
           // se selecciono Anual, edita el input aqui

        }
    }

}
```